# Writing the Pragma header in a DelegatingHandler in Asp.Net Web API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I've asked [this question over on programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158198/http-response-header-for-a-unique-request-id-for-rest-service) that's linked to this one.  I'm trying to find a suitable header, that is unlikely to be stripped, that I can use to send back a unique Request ID with every response,  even if it does not send a body.

One of the headers I considered was the `Pragma` header, as looking at the spec it appears to be intended not only for the additional `no-cache` HTTP 1.0 backwards-compatibility value, but also for application-specific values, so I should be able to use it.  It should be possible, for example, to send something like `no-cache; requestid=id`.

So in a `DelegatingHandler` I tried writing to it with my ID:

```
//HttpResponseMessage Response; 
Response.Headers.Add("pragma", "some_value");
```

But it arrives at the client with `no-cache`; always.  I think WebAPI automatically sends caching headers consistent with caching being switched off,  which includes the `Pragma` one.

So, how do I make sure my value is maintained and not overwritten?

Comment: what is the problem with using your custom `x-mycompany-myheader` header?

Comment: Just the likelihood of it getting stripped by proxies etc.  Clients could be mobile phones or servers behind corporate proxies (ours is particularly aggressive, for example) and so I really want one that is not likely to get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cracked it, the answer is to make sure you also set the `CacheControl` header on the HttpResponseMessage, which then bypasses some *slightly* fishy logic in `System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler` ([I've opened a discussion on CodePlex about this](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/389092); I think the logic needs to be changed).

So instead of

```
//HttpResponseMessage Response;
Response.Headers.Add("pragma", "some_value");
```

You have to do:

```
Response.Headers.CacheControl = 
  new System.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue() 
  { 
    NoCache = true 
  };
Response.Headers.Add("pragma", "some_value");
```

(I've used NoCache since the current API default is to switch caching off for all responses).